# Using postgres to break JSON column into Question and Answer columns?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a large JSON column that I would like to break into two columns with multiple records instead of a separate column for each component. Example of the way data looks below.

| Data | Json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"Q1":"A1", "Q2":"A2", "Q3":"A3"}] |
| 2 | [{"Q1":"A4", "Q2":"A5", "Q3":"A6"}] |

I can break it down easily into separate columns named for each question, but for some reason am hitting a block at finding out the right way to break it into just two columns.  Example of structure I am looking to create below.

| Data | Question | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1 | A1 |
| 1 | Q2 | A2 |
| 1 | Q3 | A3 |
| 2 | Q1 | A4 |
| 2 | Q2 | A5 |
| 2 | Q3 | A6 |

Comment: Why is the data an array that contains an object? Is it always containing exactly one object?

Comment: It does not always contain one object, I just was lazy with typing up an example. They will always go into these two columns though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for the [`json_each` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```
SELECT data, key AS question, value AS answer
FROM example, json_each(json->0)
```

Or if there's any number of objects in the array, combine with `json_array_elements`:

```
SELECT e.data, pair.key AS question, pair.value AS answer
FROM example e, json_array_elements(e.json) AS item, json_each(item.value) AS pair
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Bergi, probably you would want to use json_each_text since your values are known to be string:

```
select data, key as Question, value as Answer 
from example, json_each_text(json->0);
```

| data | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Q1 | A1 |
| 1 | Q2 | A2 |
| 1 | Q3 | A3 |
| 2 | Q1 | A4 |
| 2 | Q2 | A5 |
| 2 | Q3 | A6 |